# Magento 2 applying filters to collection reflects in all phtml

Tags: magento2, collection, model, resource-model

I have applied a filter in a PHTML that loads in headers. The filter is below.

In Constructor:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection
```

Block Code:

```
 public function getAllCategories(){
        return $this->collection;
    }
```

In PHTML:

```
$getAllCategories =  $block->getAllCategories();
$getAllCategories->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => array($attributVaueArray)))->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');
```

But I need to get the same collection in different PHTML without filters. If I use this Model in instructor the filter is applied automatically but I need to reset it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$block->getAllCategories()->clear();
$getAllCategories =  $block->getAllCategories()->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject the Colection into your class __construct.
Try inject CollectionFactory:

In Constructor:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
```

Block Code:

```
public function getAllCategories($attributVaueArray) {
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    return $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => array($attributVaueArray)))
        ->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');
}
```

In PHTML:
Avoid complex logic inside templates -

```
$allCategories =  $block->getAllCategories($attributVaueArray);
```

After making changes - clear caches and generated/code folder